# Use Bearer Token from localstorage

Tags: reactjs, api, symfony, react-redux, superagent

So I'm creating a simple React Redux app using superagent to get some elements from the database and do some operations on them.
I used Symfony's Api platform as a backend and created a few of APIs. All my APIs are protected and need a bearer token to access them. 
I created an Authentication API using JWT.

Now I'm trying to get the data to show in my React app. I already created a functioning login form. I can use my username and password and get a token in return.

My problem though, is after I authenticate and the app redirects me to my homepage (which contains the list of elements from the db), I get an error in my console

```
("{code: 401, message: "JWT Token not found"}
code: 401
message: "JWT Token not found")
```

which means that I'm not using the bearer token in my request.

So how do I use the token inside my POST, GET and PUT requests so I can use them.

***PS:*** My token is stored inside my localstorage under the name jwtToken
here's my agent.js file:

```
import superagentPromise from 'superagent-promise';
import _superagent from 'superagent';

const superagent = superagentPromise(_superagent,global.Promise);
const API_ROOT='http://localhost:8000/api';
const responseBody = response => response.body;

let token =window.localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');;



const tokenPlugin = secured => {
    return (request) => {
        if (token && secured){
            request.set('Authorization',`Bearer ${token}`);
        }
};
};
export const requests={
    get: (url, secured = false)=>{
        return superagent.get(`${API_ROOT}${url}`).use(tokenPlugin(secured)).then(responseBody);
    },
    post: (url, body = null, secured = true) => {
        return superagent.post(`${API_ROOT}${url}`, body).use(tokenPlugin(secured)).then(responseBody);
    },
    setToken: (newJwtToken) => token = newJwtToken
    };
```

Comment: can you try to use `console.log(token)` to see if there any data ?

Comment: it returns the token, so it works fine, I had to change secured to true and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your get accepts `url` and `secured` params and maybe you are not sending the second param and it is defaulted to false and tokenPlugin is checking for `token && secured`

try `get(url, true)` where you are using the `get`.